# How to add Facebook Android SDK with @AAR

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio

As many, I am also switching to Android Studio. The Android project I have is a IntelliJ Classic project with two key dependencies: the google play services and the facebook SDK. I've swithced a project to the new Gradle-based build withthe play servies, which is rather straightforward but I fear switching the Facebook SDK library is not that easy.

I've heard and seen the usage of @aar in the dependencies. Does this dependency style exist for teh facebook SDK already? I assume there must be others out there who use the facebook sdk with a new Android Studio / Gradle based build.

It would be great to get a step-by-step instruction how to get this done.

Comment: Check out this page, it goes through how to use the SDK with Android Studio. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android-using-android-studio/3.0/

Answer (score 8):

Facebook now publishes an AAR to the Maven Central. To use it simply add an normal dependency:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.20.0')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Facebook at the moment does not provide `aar` lib.
However you can use `aar` archives from other sources or compile it yourself.

you could use :
https://github.com/mente/facebook-api-android-aar